# Mark as favorites

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I want to create a Favorites field for Opportunities object where a user can mark any opportunities as favorite and then view all his favorites by creating a new view called My Favorites. The favorites will be restricted across users. Please help to accomplish this feature. Do I need to create a field or can this be achieved by any alternate way?

Comment: How familiar are you with Apex?  Are you able to write code?  For the most seamless integration, you will likely need to implement some

Answer (score 0):

How about to add a new custom checkbox field like "MyFavorite__c" to the object?

Comment: I added that.. I also created a new view to filter marked records. But the requirement is each user should be able to see only his records which he marked as favorite  i.e if user A has marked 3 records as favorites, user B should not be seeing any records marked as favorite and he can select his own favorites which doesn't affect A.

Comment: But first the user should be able to see all the records to be able to select some of them as favorite?